# Excel VBA graphQL http request "run time error -2147012744 The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response"

Tags: excel, vba, api, http-headers, httprequest

I have written VBA code to retrieve JSON result through GraphQL API but faced run time error

> -2147012744 The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

My VBA code is following and I am facing the error at .send reqQueryAsBody statement

[API documentation](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10628564/TVKA5f2x)

```
Dim req As Object
Dim reqURL As String
Dim BearerToken As String
Dim JsonResult As String

'Declare Query related Dimensions
Dim reqQueryName As String
Dim reqvarName As String
Dim reqQueryAsBody As String

'Declare Json Dimensions
Dim JSONa, element, var As Object, rep As Variant, e As Variant, i As Variant

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
              
    'To check whether Query is Typed or Not in provided space in Main Excel Sheet
    If IsEmpty(sht.Range("reqQuery").value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Kindly Type requested Query in Provided Space in Main Sheet", vbInformation, "Info"
        sht.Range("reqQuery").Activate
        Exit Sub
    
    ElseIf IsEmpty(sht.Range("reqVariable").value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Kindly Select requested variable in Provided Space in Main Sheet", vbInformation, "Info"
        sht.Range("reqVariable").Activate
        Exit Sub
        
    Else

        reqQueryName = sht.Range("reqQuery").value
        reqvarName = sht.Range("reqVariable").value
        BearerToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
        
        'html URL
        reqURL = "http://tddrapi.trustfci.com/graphql"
        
        Query Prepare Query as per Structure
        reqQueryAsBody = "{""query"": { " & reqQueryName & "" & vbCrLf & _
                    "   (" & vbCrLf & "        offset:0, " & vbCrLf & _
                    "        orderby: """ & reqvarName & """, " & vbCrLf & _
                    "        order: ""asc"" " & vbCrLf & _
                    "   ) " & vbCrLf & _
                    "       {" & vbCrLf & _
                    "           " & reqvarName & " " & vbCrLf & _
                    "       }" & vbCrLf & _
                    "  }" & vbCrLf & "}"

        Debug.Print reqQueryAsBody

        Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

        With req
            .Open "POST", reqURL, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
            .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & BearerToken
            .send reqQueryAsBody
        End With

        debug.print req.responseText
        JsonResult = req.responseText
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, the service is stopped,isn't it.

```
`$ ping tddrapi.trustfci.com

PING tddrapi.trustfci.com (70.141.38.184) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C

--- tddrapi.trustfci.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7248ms`
```